# Property T Versus Property A

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, geometric-group-theory

Kazhdan Property  T for  a locally  compact  group  is  defined  in terms  of  the unitary  dual. Namely, a   group  has  property  $T$  if  the identity  is  an  isolated  point  in the  space  of  unitary  representations  with  the  Fell  topology. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kazhdan%27s_property_(T) .  Some  remarkable groups  which  have  property  $T$  are  given  by  finitely  generated  discrete groups  with  expanders  in  their  Cayley  graph, and  thus  incapable  of  coarsely  embedding  into  a  HIlbert  space.

On the  other  hand,  Property  $A$   metric  spaces (thus  also  for  finitely  generated  grous  via  the  Cayley  graph)  is   defined  in  terms  of  generalizations  of  Foelner  Sets, see http://www.ams.org/notices/200804/tx080400474p.pdf    givings  conditions  for  such  a  group  to  coarsely  embedd  in a  Hilbert  space.

Is  there  any  known  dicotomy   for  finitely  presented  groups,  as  for  a  discrete,  finitely  generated group  having   property  $T$ and  Property $A$ should  be   finite. What  is  a  good  reference  to  this  fact?

Comment: No, linear groups have Property A (Guentner-Higson-Weinberger), and this includes many infinite Property T groups, such as $SL_3(\mathbf{Z})$.

Comment: I am far from an expert in these matters, but in some sense amenability, the Haagerup property and Property (T) are all "equivariant" conditions, definable in terms of the Fourier or Fourier-Stieltjes algebra of a group. Property A, a.k.a. exactness, is not equivariant

Comment: As @Ycor has pointed out, the emphasis in your first paragraph does not seem quite correct. It is far harder to find groups that do not coarsely embed into Hilbert space, than to find groups with Property (T).

Comment: @YemonChoi one strength of amenability is that it's also definable in a non-equivariant way (e.g. Følner sets) and in particular it's a coarse invariant (=quasi-isometry invariant)

Comment: @YCor Good point; thank you for the correction/precision